# How to add extract specific text using NLP (customized tags) ?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to extract specific tags from a paragraph of text using stanford CoreNLP,  something like "randomized", "randomised",  which for right now I can't find a matching NEG tags associated with it.

What is the best way to do this ? Should I construct a specific NER tag ? Or should I get specific annotator ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into RegexNER:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html